# FatalExecutionEngineError when calling GetSystemTime/SetSystemTime

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke, fatal-error

I have written a small util in an app that syncs the time from a time server, which uses the Windows API functions `GetSystemTime` and `SetSystemTime`. It was all working fine, but now every time I call `Get/SetSystemTime` I get an error:

> ```
> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected  
> Message:  
> The runtime has encountered a fatal error.  
> The address of the error was at 0x792bee10, on thread 0x48c.  
> The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR  
> or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code.  
> Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop
> or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
> ```

Now as the only unsafe code is a call to the Win32 functions (is that even unsafe??) it seems it cant be in my code - that and i havent changed anythig since it was actually working...

Any ideas what might be going on here?

The Win32 calls are made using:

```
public class SystemTime
        {
            public ushort Year;
            public ushort Month;
            public ushort DayOfWeek;
            public ushort Day;
            public ushort Hour;
            public ushort Minute;
            public ushort Second;
            public ushort Millisecond;

            public static implicit operator SystemTime(DateTime dt)
            {
                SystemTime rval = new SystemTime();
                rval.Year = (ushort)dt.Year;
                rval.Month = (ushort)dt.Month;
                rval.Day = (ushort)dt.Day;
                rval.DayOfWeek = (ushort)dt.DayOfWeek;
                rval.Hour = (ushort)dt.Hour;
                rval.Minute = (ushort)dt.Minute;
                rval.Second = (ushort)dt.Second;
                rval.Millisecond = (ushort)dt.Millisecond;
                return rval;
            }

            public static implicit operator DateTime(SystemTime st)
            {
                return new DateTime(st.Year, st.Month, st.Day, st.Hour, st.Minute, st.Second, st.Millisecond);
            }
        }; 

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemTime")]
        public extern static void Win32GetSystemTime(ref SystemTime sysTime); 
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetSystemTime")]
        public extern static bool Win32SetSystemTime(ref SystemTime sysTime);
```

EDIT: Now the very same code (unmodified) is giving me an AccessViolation ???

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory.  
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: What P/Invoke signature of GetSystemTime do you use?

Comment: Note that usually using P/Invoke definitions from http://pinvoke.net/ is the best bet. (At least as a starting point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining SYSTEMTIME as a class, when you pass it by reference you are actually passing a pointer to a pointer but on the unmanaged side it is expecting a pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure.

Either change your definition of SYSTEMTIME to a struct and pass it by reference as you are doing now. Or leave it as a class and change your declares to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void GetSystemTime([Out] SYSTEMTIME systemTime);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public extern static uint SetSystemTime([In] SYSTEMTIME systemTime);
```

Personally, I would change it to a struct.

Comment: I will try this, but it doesnt explaion 3 entirely different behaviours from unchanged code -1) works fine, then 2) FataException then 3) AccessViolation ?? Surely something more is going on...?

Comment: When accessing the pointer to a pointer the system will attempt to read or write at the location pointed to. This will either be protected memory in which case you'll get an AccessViolation or it may corrupt memory that is used by the .Net runtime in which case you'll get a FatalExecutionEngineError, or even worse it may silently corrupt a value that you will unknowingly use later, it all depends on what is in the first 4(or 8) bytes of the SystemTime structure. As to it working before, I think you must have changed something since as written it should never have worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the functions from MSDN, the PInvoke signatures you should be using are:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SYSTEMTIME
{
   public ushort Year;
   public ushort Month;
   public ushort DayOfWeek;
   public ushort Day;
   public ushort Hour;
   public ushort Minute;
   public ushort Second;
   public ushort Milliseconds;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void GetSystemTime(out SYSTEMTIME systemTime);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME systemTime);
```

Are you using something different?

Comment: Edited my original question to include the code I am using. Thought it was irrelevant given it was working ok before.

Comment: @Aaron: Two things: (a) The method names don't start with `Win32` and (b) `SetSystemTime` returns a `uint`, not a `bool`.

Comment: Should return type matter here? it is interpretted as a bool no? And i actually ignore the return value in my code anyway...? Also, I alias all my Win32 calls with the prefix 'Win32'. it makes no difference if you specify the dll entry point for the functions, as i have above...

Comment: changing return type effects nothing though, I tried it. I find prefix with Win32 helps to recognise them when scattered throughout my code ;-)

Comment: @Aaron: Didn't know that. Thanks for mentioning it.